# Getting Server-side Javascript to work for me

Tags: javascript, server-side

I am wondering how to install a Javascript runtime engine to work with an Apache HTTP server. My aim is to run server-side Javascript.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to clarify why you want to do this.

If you're just looking to execute JavaScript code, [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) will get you the ability to run javascript within a Java application. However, since its not in a web browser you won't have any access to any sort of DOM.

Other than that, JavaScript is mostly a language that was intended to run in a web browser on the client.

Comment: However, see http://nodejs.org/ for server-side js.  Unfortunately I have no experience with it other than knowing the name.